# split string with vertical tab as delimiter using vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

How can I split a string in vba with vertical tab as delimiter.

```
strWriters = Mid("Richenn M.(there a delimiter here)QA'er:", 9, Len("Richenn M.(there a delimiter here)QA'er:"))
LArray = VBA.Split(Selection.Text, Chr(103))
strWriter = LArray(0)
MsgBox LArray(0)
```

i tried to searched for the char equivalent but it returns an error for char(103)

It says type mismatch.

Comment: Why don't you ask the debug (ctrl-g) window for the code? For example this will tell you the code for the space: `?asc(mid("Hello World",6,1))` Also its `CHR(103)` not `CHAR(103)`

Comment: Record yourself using the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Step-1-Start-with-the-macro-recorder-6DC53056-1DE1-4483-AA07-63E4E0EFE3C2) performing a Data ► Text-to-Columns, Delimited, Other (**|**), Finish operation.

Comment: It returns a type mismatch error even if i use either of your answers. And i found out that the delimiter for vertical tab is chr(11) but even though, it still returns an type mismatch error

Comment: Is `LArray` dimmed as a variant? Make sure `Option Base 1` is not written at the top of the module

Comment: Yes. It is dimmed as variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **vertical tab** character is ASCII &H0B hex or 011 dec¹. VBA uses the [Chr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465.aspx) and [Asc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264313.aspx) functions while the worksheet uses the [CHAR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-BBD249C8-B36E-4A91-8017-1C133F9B837A) and [CODE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CODE-function-C32B692B-2ED0-4A04-BDD9-75640144B928) functions.

Your syntax appears largely correct but there is some confusion as to what you are actually working on. You start with a string constant and string variable (e.g. `strWriters`) then immediately discard those and work with `Selection.Text`.

```
Sub how2split()
    Dim str As String, strWriters As String, a As Long, LArray As Variant

    str = "Richenn M." & Chr(&HB) & "QA'er:"
    'alternate
    'str = Join(Array("Richenn M.", "QA'er:"), Chr(&HB))

    Debug.Print str

    LArray = Split(str, Chr(11))

    For a = LBound(LArray) To UBound(LArray)
        Debug.Print LArray(a) & " is at position " & a
    Next a
End Sub
```

The [Debug.Print](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358847.aspx) command send output to the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx).

---

¹ <sub>ASCII 103 is a lower-case G (e.g. `Chr(103)` produces a `g`).</sub>

Comment: I had also been planning to show the ASCII code of the vertical tab with `Debug.Print Asc(Mid(str, 11, 1))` but since it just happened to also be the 11th character from the left, I thought that might generate some confusion.